# Java servlet method call squence lead to different result

Tags: java

I use SpringBoot 2.1.1 with Java 11,when i write a http interface, i need to return a excel file to client, and i fill the file with Java code, then use HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write() to send the file.The puzzle thing is first call HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write() then call HttpServletResponse.setContentType(), the client cannot accept the content-type. where is the issue?

SpringBoot 2.1.1 with Java 11.

case 1:

```
byte[] errorFile = new byte[0];
// fill errorFile...
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(errorFile);
response.setHeader("Error-File", "True");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

In this call sequence, if errorFile has a short content, it will be fine, server will write content-type and the header(Error-File) to clients, but if the errorFile has a long content, clients cannot get the content-type and the header(Error-File).

case 2:

```
byte[] errorFile = new byte[0];
// fill errorFile...
response.setHeader("Error-File", "True");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(errorFile);
```

If i use this call sequence, it will be fine in any length of errorFile.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that an HTTP response contains

1. the status,
2. then the headers,
3. then the body.

So if you first write the body, it's too late to write the headers.

Comment: ...and I'd imagine the reason the wrong way works for small files is probably due to a buffer.

Comment: But when i write a small file, it works well, it is really puzzle me.